Where to get 13F data in excel format?
I am trying to do a project and analyse 13F data from some most followed fund managers or individuals (e.g. Michael Burry). However, I couldn't find anywhere where I can get the data in a properly "analysable" format. Does anyone know where I can get this data and not have to download 13F item by item.
Thank you.
